# SQL Server service-broker 500 messages limit

Tags: sql-server, limit, service-broker

Thought I've reached beyond noob questions, but I may not. ^^

I am building some custom, dedicated data warehouse on top of trigger-based change capture technology, using SSB.

- 2 different ways to load data from database A to B : initial vs regular load
- While initial load implements temporary queue/service on-the-fly, regular load has permanent ones. Both are using the same receiver endpoint and the same transform process
- While initial load successfully deals with millions of messages, regular hits the ground at exactly **500**

When I generate INSERT (for example) operations on a table, I can notice some threshold:

- 499 operations => 499 single-row message sent => 499 messages received => conversation state goes "CLOSED" => no lock from connection that issued operations
- 500 operations => 500 single-row message sent => 500 messages received => conversation state stuck to 'CONVERSING' => remaining lock from connection that issued operations
- 501 operations => 500 single-row message sent => 500 messages received => conversation state stuck to 'CONVERSING' => remaining lock from connection that issued operations
- (and so on)

I browsed my code, looking for this specific '500' value, with no way. Makes me wonder about some limitation from database A broker, but I can't figure out which one. Any idea?

**EDIT after SQLApostle comment**
My first thought was that my DB restore had left another broker with the same ID running on former box (something I already experienced, with DB versionning on the same instance) which endpoint could have been broadcasted as well as new box'es, that could explain the difference. But I detached the whole stuff on former instance, so it can't be running anymore, IMO.

Thanks in advance,

Jean-Yves

Comment: What are SQL Server Versions on Databases A and B . Can you replicate this using the same code on another server ?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 (12.0.5000), sorry. I used to run the code on another server (changed former development server 3 weeks ago) but at that time I didn't notice anything. Not sure I took a sharp look at that, honestly.

Comment: Is this remote? If acks don't flow from B to A (eg. bad route), it could behave this way.

Comment: Hello Remus, sorry for the late answer (holiday ^^). There is no route for the time being, being a proof of concept, this is local process (A and B on the instance)